# Features on a vector layer to have a scalable stroke?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to make some kind of line-drawing editor over OpenStreet map using OpenLayers. I am able to draw points, connect them into lines, and it all looks good, but if I unzoom, stroke width is the same as on previous zoom (instead of being smaller). And if I unzoom al the way up to 0, line width (stroke) is still the same.

Now, I made this work the way I want it using context on Style, but I don't like the way it works...

**QUESTIONS:**

Is there some kind of setting to make all lines scalable when I am changing zoom (adapt stroke width based on current zoom level)?

Can I set stroke width in meters or millimeters?

Answer (score 2):

**My solution at the moment:**

1. Define a context object with method for calculating line width (this can be done in style definition, I wrote it like this for readability):

   ```
   var context = 
   {
       getWidth: function (feature) 
       {       
           //I am setting attribute widthInMeters to each feature, and I am using that
           //for a calculation of line width, where 1m = 100px
           var r = map.getResolution() * 10000000;
           var w = feature.attributes.widthInMeters * (100 / parseFloat(Math.round(r * 100) /100).toFixed(2));
           return w;
       }
   };
   ```
2. Define a style with context and add it to vector layer:

   ```
   var style = new OpenLayers.Style(
   {
       strokeWidth: "${getWidth}",  //Context method call to get the width  (context.getWidth)
       strokeLinecap: "square"  
   }, 
   { 
       context: context 
   })
   ```

Now, this works. If width of a line is 1 meter, it is calculating the correct length on every zoom change, and it looks good. But, this setup is really complicated on larger code (my code is a larger code) so I am trying to find a way to do this in style definition, and not to manually calculate it...

*If someone suggests a better solution, it will be accepted as an answer.*